# How to make calls using a pool of phone numbers as caller IDs in Voximplant?

Tags: voximplant

I want to make calls using a pool of phone numbers as caller IDs. I want my script to chose a random number of what I have and show it to my customers. Can I do this with Voximplant?

Answer (score 0):

There's no "random caller ID" in Voximplant, but you can easily do it with common JS, like this:

```
//pool of disposable callerIDs
let number_pool = ["73832349068",
"79666667368",
"79666667369",
"19073314185"]

//random index generation
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}
let index;

//incoming call leg
VoxEngine.addEventListener(AppEvents.CallAlerting, function (e) {

  //picking random callerID
  index=getRandomInt(number_pool.length);
  const confirmedCallerId = number_pool[index];

  //outbound call leg to call destination from randomly selected callerID
  const out = VoxEngine.callPSTN(e.destination, confirmedCallerId);
  
 VoxEngine.easyProcess(e.call, out);
});
```